# using files with runnable jars in cmd

Tags: java, file, cmd, resources

I am working on a code that is not mine and I'd like to be able to run it on other computers using the cmd. 
On eclipse we use this

`MazeWritable maze = new MazeWritable("layouts/mediumClassic.lay");`

to refer to layouts, if I go through the different calls it makes it goes like this :

```
public MazeWritable(String filename) throws MazeException
{
super(filename);
}
```

then super goes to

```
public Maze(String filename) throws MazeException
{
    try{
        System.out.println("Layout file is "+filename);
        //Lecture du fichier pour déterminer la taille du maze
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(filename); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
```

When I try using eclipse to make a runnable jar of my project, it does not include the file layouts/, which on the project is next to the referenced libraries, and even though I try to put it in, in the cmd it does not want to see it, is there something that i missed ? 
I tried with the manifest but it does not work (and I am not sure of what I'm doing).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

## 1

Put the `layouts` folder in the root of your JAR file and try to load it as a resource:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("layouts/mediumClassic.lay");
```

## 2

Put the `layouts` folder outside your JAR file and load the resource as you did it already.

I would prefer the second version, but if you like to package everything together you should go with the first version.